# Is it possible to make a website that is horizontally AND vertically scrollable?

Tags: javascript, jquery, css, horizontal-scrolling, vertical-scrolling

I am trying to make an experimental narrative website that tells two different stories in a page. The website is currently just horizontally scrollable, and I just have a big fixed image top of images that has a big hole in the middle. I originally had a clickable image at the end of horizontal scroll so that it links to the another story, but I wonder if I can have horizontal scroll AND vertical scroll so that it shows different images at the same time? Like when the user scroll vertically, horizontal scroll stops; and when the user scroll horizontally, vertical scroll stops? thanks.

[here's a reference image here](https://i.stack.imgur.com/8QUUg.png)

Comment: look up [parallax scrolling](https://www.google.com/webhp?sourceid=chrome-instant&ion=1&espv=2&ie=UTF-8#q=parallax%20scrolling) libraries. you're still going to need to learn how to implement them but its a good start.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Yes. One way to do it would be by using `jQuery` to capture `mousewheel` events to fire a custom scrolling function while hiding the default scrollbars using `overflow: hidden` to avoid any weird behaviour. So it is really about creating a controlled environment where the changes occur with event handles rather than native browser "scrolling".

Have a look at my basic example: [view on **codepen**](http://codepen.io/azizn/pen/GZdXbO)

```js
// jQuery Next or First / Prev or Last plugin

$.fn.nextOrFirst = function(selector){
    var next = this.next(selector);
    return (next.length) ? next : this.prevAll(selector).last();
};

$.fn.prevOrLast = function(selector){
    var prev = this.prev(selector);
    return (prev.length) ? prev : this.nextAll(selector).last();
};

// Scroll Functions

function scrollSection(parent, dir) {
 var active = "active",
    section = parent.find("."+active);
  if (dir == "prev") {
    section.removeClass(active).prevOrLast().addClass(active);
  } else {
    section.removeClass(active).nextOrFirst().addClass(active);
  }
}

// Bind Scroll function to mouse wheel event

$('#vertical, #horizontal').on('mousewheel wheel', function(e){
  if (e.originalEvent.wheelDelta /120 > 0) { // scroll up event
    scrollSection($(this), "prev");
  } else { // scroll down event
    scrollSection($(this));
  }
});
```

```css
html, body, #vertical {
  color: #FFF; margin: 0; padding: 0;
  height: 100%; overflow: hidden; }
  
#horizontal {
  height: 70vh; width: 70vh;
  position: fixed; margin: auto;
  top: 0; left: 0; right: 0; bottom: 0;
  display: flex;
  border-radius: 100%;
  overflow: hidden; }

section {
  height: 0%;
  box-sizing: border-box;
  transition: 1s;
  overflow: hidden; }

#horizontal section {
  width: 100%; height: 100%;
  min-width:0%;
  text-align: center; }

.inner { padding: 3em; }

#vertical section.active { height: 100%; }

#horizontal section.active { min-width: 100%; }
```

```html
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/2.1.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
<div id="horizontal">
  <section class="active" style="background:Black"><div class="inner">Horizontal 1</div></section>
  <section style="background:BurlyWood"><div class="inner">Horizontal 2</div></section>
  <section style="background:MediumSlateBlue"><div class="inner">Horizontal 3</div></section>
</div>
<div id="vertical">
  <section class="active" style="background:SteelBlue"><div class="inner">Vertical 1</div></section>
  <section style="background:DarkSlateBlue"><div class="inner">Vertical 2</div></section>
  <section style="background:HotPink"><div class="inner">Vertical 3</div></section>
</div>
```

You could even make it slide both boxes at the same time:

```js
// jQuery Next or First / Prev or Last plugin

$.fn.nextOrFirst = function(selector){
    var next = this.next(selector);
    return (next.length) ? next : this.prevAll(selector).last();
};

$.fn.prevOrLast = function(selector){
    var prev = this.prev(selector);
    return (prev.length) ? prev : this.nextAll(selector).last();
};

// Scroll Functions

function scrollSection(parent, dir) {
 var active = "active",
    section = parent.find("."+active);
  if (dir == "prev") {
    section.removeClass(active).prevOrLast().addClass(active);
  } else {
    section.removeClass(active).nextOrFirst().addClass(active);
  }
}

// Bind Scroll function to mouse wheel event

$('body').on('mousewheel wheel', function(e){
  if (e.originalEvent.wheelDelta /120 > 0) { // scroll up event
    scrollSection( $('#vertical'), "prev");
    scrollSection( $('#horizontal'), "prev");
  } else { // scroll down event
    scrollSection( $('#vertical') );
    scrollSection( $('#horizontal') );
  }
});
```

```css
html, body, #vertical {
  color: #FFF; margin: 0; padding: 0;
  height: 100%; overflow: hidden; }
  
#horizontal {
  height: 70vh; width: 70vh;
  position: fixed; margin: auto;
  top: 0; left: 0; right: 0; bottom: 0;
  display: flex;
  border-radius: 100%;
  overflow: hidden; }

section {
  height: 0%;
  box-sizing: border-box;
  transition: 1s;
  overflow: hidden; }

#horizontal section {
  width: 100%; height: 100%;
  min-width:0%;
  text-align: center; }

.inner { padding: 3em; }

#vertical section.active { height: 100%; }

#horizontal section.active { min-width: 100%; }
```

```html
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/2.1.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
<div id="horizontal">
  <section class="active" style="background:Black"><div class="inner">Horizontal 1</div></section>
  <section style="background:BurlyWood"><div class="inner">Horizontal 2</div></section>
  <section style="background:MediumSlateBlue"><div class="inner">Horizontal 3</div></section>
</div>
<div id="vertical">
  <section class="active" style="background:SteelBlue"><div class="inner">Vertical 1</div></section>
  <section style="background:DarkSlateBlue"><div class="inner">Vertical 2</div></section>
  <section style="background:HotPink"><div class="inner">Vertical 3</div></section>
</div>
```

Comment: your script does not run in Firefox. But it looks nice in Chrome

Comment: @Type-Style Thanks, seems that Firefox recognizes the `wheel` event instead of `mousewheel`. Updated accordingly.

Comment: Thank you so much. This is amazing.